# Как преобразовать массив в JS?

Tags: javascript, массивы, база-данных, reactjs

У меня есть массив, который вытягивается из базы данных с такой структурой ( пример):

```
[
  {
    Receipt_Id: 58,
    Subscription_Id: 4, 
    Count: 2,
    User_Id: 3
  },
  {
    Receipt_Id: 58,
    Subscription_Id: 5, 
    Count: 2,
    User_Id: 3
  },
  {
    Receipt_Id: 59,
    Subscription_Id: 11, 
    Count: 1,
    User_Id: 3
  },
  ...
];
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать алгоритм, который преобразует этот массив в вид наподобие:

```
[
  {
    Receipt_Id: 58,
    Subscription_Id: [4, 5, 6], 
    Count: [2, 2, 3]
  },
  {
    Receipt_Id: 59,
    Subscription_Id: [11, 12, 10, 5],
    Count: [1, 2, 2, 2]
  },
  {
    Receipt_Id: 60,
    Subscription_Id: [12],
    Count: [5]
  }
]
```

Я пишу на JavaScript'е и React'е.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [ассоциативным массивом Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
// Исходный массив
const source = [
  {
    Receipt_Id: 58,
    Subscription_Id: 4, 
    Count: 2,
    User_Id: 3
  },
  {
    Receipt_Id: 58,
    Subscription_Id: 5, 
    Count: 2,
    User_Id: 3
  },
  {
    Receipt_Id: 59,
    Subscription_Id: 11, 
    Count: 1,
    User_Id: 3
  }
];

// Сюда будем складывать результат
const dest = new Map();

source.forEach( s => {
  // Если элемента нет в массиве, то добавляем
  if (!dest.has(s.Receipt_Id)) {
    dest.set(s.Receipt_Id, {
      Receipt_Id: s.Receipt_Id,
      Subscription_Id: [],
      Count: []
    });
  } else { // Иначе обновляем данные
    const v = dest.get(s.Receipt_Id);
    v.Subscription_Id.push(s.Subscription_Id);
    v.Count.push(s.Count);
    dest.set(s.Receipt_Id, v);
  }
});

// Вывод
console.log(dest.values());
```